# Why my JavaScript-generated tree is cropped?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, tree

In my project I'm using the hierarchical tree from here:
http://javascript.ru/ui/tree

```
function tree_toggle(event) {
    event = event || window.event
    var clickedElem = event.target || event.srcElement

    if (!hasClass(clickedElem, 'Expand')) {
        return // клик не там
    }

    // Node, на который кликнули
    var node = clickedElem.parentNode
    if (hasClass(node, 'ExpandLeaf')) {
        return // клик на листе
    }

    // определить новый класс для узла
    var newClass = hasClass(node, 'ExpandOpen') ? 'ExpandClosed' : 'ExpandOpen'
    // заменить текущий класс на newClass
    // регексп находит отдельно стоящий open|close и меняет на newClass
    var re = /(^|\s)(ExpandOpen|ExpandClosed)(\s|$)/
    node.className = node.className.replace(re, '$1' + newClass + '$3')
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the recursive Django-template to generate this tree:

index.html:

```
   <div style="position:fixed; width:300px;">
        <div onclick="tree_toggle(arguments[0])">
            <div id="tfheader">
                <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="/help/search">
                        <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="Поиск" class="tfbutton">
                </form>
                <div class="tfclear"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="overflow: scroll">
                <ul class="Container">
                    <li class="IsRoot">
                        <div class="Expand">

                        </div>

                        <div class="Content">
                            Содержание
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {{ spaceless }}
                    {% include 'list.html' with data=list %}
                    {{ endspaceless }}
                </ul>
            </div>
   </div>
```

list.html:

```
<ul class="Container">
    <li class="Node ExpandOpen" style="overflow: scroll">
        <div class="Expand"></div>
        <div class="Content">
            <a href="/help/{{data.name}}">
                {{data.leaf}}
            </a>
        </div>
        {% for item in data.decendent %}
            {% include 'list.html' with data=item %}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately, this tree crops in the end of the window's height and doesn't even scroll up or down:

[image]

My css file for this page:

```
.Container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.Container li {
    list-style-type: none;
}



/* indent for all tree children excepts root */
.Node {
    background-image : url(/media/pic/docs/i.gif);
    background-position : top left;
    background-repeat : repeat-y;
    margin-left: 18px;
    zoom: 1;
}

.IsRoot {
    margin-left: 0;
}


/* left vertical line (grid) for all nodes */
.IsLast {
    background-image: url(/media/pic/docs/i_half.gif);
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
}

.ExpandOpen .Expand {
    background-image: url(/media/pic/docs/expand_minus.gif);
}

/* closed is higher priority than open */
.ExpandClosed .Expand {
    background-image: url(/media/pic/docs/expand_plus.gif);
}

/* highest priority */
.ExpandLeaf .Expand {
    background-image: url(/media/pic/docs/expand_leaf.gif);
}

.Content {
    min-height: 18px;
    margin-left:18px;
}

* html  .Content {
    height: 18px; 
}

.Expand {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
}


.ExpandLoading   {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(/media/pic/docs/expand_loading.gif);
}



.ExpandOpen .Container {
    display: block;
}

.ExpandClosed .Container {
    display: none;
}

.ExpandOpen .Expand, .ExpandClosed .Expand {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ExpandLeaf .Expand {
    cursor: auto;
}
```

How to add the scrolling to this tree?
Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Have you tried `overflow` on the `ul` or `body`, etc.? Can you experiment with the inspector which element needs the `overflow` property?

Comment: Yes, I tried it: "overflow: scroll". No effect at all.

Comment: Can you give us a url to your page or put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Could this be a line height issue within the css? +1 for jsfiddle please.

Comment: @jcuenod unfortunately, the whole project is accessible only under the vpn connection and is closed for the public access. In addition, I'm using the Django framework, which has the specific syntax for templates. I can copy-and-paste my code to jsfiddle, but it will make no sense, because jsfiddle doesn't understand django templates language and doesn't have an access to my file system where node names for tree are extracted from.

Comment: @MattWritesCode added css rules for my page to the post.

Comment: @Xufox yes, neither .Container nor li elements with "overflow: scroll" take much effect.

Comment: @MattWritesCode what exactly did you mean under 'line height issue' term?